# Visual Studio 2015/17 Connected Service OData - UserID & Password

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2015, odata, visual-studio-2017

I have a web service running that requires a user id and password to access.

https://app.notmyrealdomain.uk:8120/WebService/OData/$metadata

If I enter the above address in my browser it will correctly prompt for a user ID and password before showing the metadata.

When trying to configure the endpoint address using the Visual Studio 2015/2017 Connected Service OData it doesn't prompt for the user id and password and gives an error "Connected Services - Cannot Access" and won't let me complete the wizard.

How can I use Connected Service OData with a user ID and password?

Thx, Darrell

Comment: Any success on this one? Perhaps it is not possible. In my case it is not possible to recreate the service locally without a password.

Comment: Post full steps how to add & invoking OData in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround for this - you need to save metadata file locally and use it when adding Service Reference.

1. Open http://myWeb:8145/DynamicsNav90_Desa/OData/$metadata in the browser and save it on disk
2. Use path to this file during adding service reference in Visual Studio: List item

[image]

For me it works perfectly.

Comment: Post full steps how to add & invoking OData in ASP.Net.